# React component with useContext has 'was not wrapped in act(...)' warning

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a page of my React app that works like this (trying not to dump mounds of code):

1. click on an item from a list
2. a sidepanel opens up with details of that item
3. in that sidepanel, set the name and price of the item and then press save (this is saved in state using hooks and useContext)
4. if either is blank or invalid, show an error

To start with, the test item has a valid price. The test for entering a blank price passes:

```
it("should show an error and not fire the callback when you try and save a blank price", () => {
  clickFirstItem(wrapper);
  setFirstPrice(wrapper, "");                             // set the price to blank
  expect(wrapper.find(".alert-danger").length).toBe(0);
  wrapper.find(".btn-primary").simulate("click");
  expect(wrapper.find(".alert-danger").length).toBe(1);
  expect(onSave).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

But the test for entering an invalid price is failing and giving the warning "Warning: An update to Services inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)":

```
it("should show an error and not fire the callback when you try and save an invalid price", () => {
  clickFirstItem(wrapper);
  setFirstPrice(wrapper, "xxx");
  expect(wrapper.find(".alert-danger").length).toBe(0);
  wrapper.find(".btn-primary").simulate("click");
  expect(wrapper.find(".alert-danger").length).toBe(1);   // this is failing
  expect(onSave).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

And yes I am sure that my component is showing an error when I set the price to "xxx".

I have tried using `act()` [as described on the React site](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/02/06/react-v16.8.0.html#testing-hooks), but it still fails and gives the 'act' warning:

```
it("should show an error and not fire the callback when you try and save an invalid price", () => {
  let container = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  act(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(<ProductsPage items={itemsData} onSave={onSave} />, container);
  });

  container.querySelector("table tbody tr:first-of-type").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", { bubbles: true }));
  expect(container.querySelectorAll(".alert-danger").length).toBe(0);

  act(() => {
    container.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']")[0].value = "xxx";
  });

  container.querySelector(".btn-primary").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", { bubbles: true }));
  expect(container.querySelectorAll(".alert-danger").length).toBe(1); // this is failing

  document.body.removeChild(container);
  container = null;
});
```

Trying to wrap more of the code in `act` to get rid of the error causes other problems.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Normally this error shouldn't appear in tests, placing `act` by trial and error won't help. The component likely does asynchronous updates that can't be processed by Enzyme. You shouldn't use ReactDOM.render because it's orthogonal to Enzyme. The problem is very specific to the component which you didn't post. *trying not to dump mounds of code* - consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem. It should not contain a bunch of irrelevant code, as the name suggests.

Comment: @EstusFlask yes the component does call ‘await props.save()’ when the save button is pressed. the test is pressing the save button and the ‘expect’ is the next line — so how do I test this?

Comment: In the test, `await` for the promise that `save` returns before asserting the effect that it causes.